# How to export config file to use in the same workspace - monorepo

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, monorepo

I create a monorepo (lerna and yarn workspace) with packages are admin page and client page.

Both of them are using the Create-React-App template and use the same config. Ex: craco.config.js, antd.customize.less. I just wonder how can I create a config which use by both of them then I don't need to change a lot of files if I want to modify the config.

How about create another package with these configs, then add this package into both of them. I think it's available with the js file. But I'm not sure about other file extensions.

This is my packages now:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a good idea to pull your common configurations and tools into separate package and use this package as a source of truth. It might be tempting to install and configure all at the top level of monorepo, but it will make taking some package out painful.

Assuming that you made a separate package and put there just three files: `package.json`,  `antd.customize.less` and `craco.config.js` - all in root of the package. After you install, all this files would be available in other packages. So, in your *local* `craco.config.js` you will make:

```js
module.exports = require('package-name/craco.config.js');
```

And for `.less`, it is hugely depend on your build toolchain. For example, if you can import less files into JS, you can do `import "package-name/antd.customize.less"`. For importing into less with css-loader it would be `@import "~package-name/antd.customize.less"` and so on. I might be  fuzzy on the details here, honestly, but in general, you can use any kind of files from package. It is only needed for your toolchain to know how to interpret those files.